# Add documents to library through an item in a list with Web Parts, and have document fields auto-populate from list item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, sharepoint-list, sharepoint-library

In Sharepoint 2013, I have a custom list that I want to "map" documents to. I am using 'Form Web Parts' in my list to look at my library and filter the documents that match. No issues there.

My problem is adding documents to the library, while looking at an item in the list, by dragging and dropping the documents into the web part. I can drag and drop just fine, but the document field that I am filtering on is not populated to the document. So, when I refresh the page the document is "lost" from my item view. Is there a way to have certain fields for documents be auto-populated when they are dropped in, based on the list item that is currently being viewed?

Note: I am using SP 2013, but only have Workflows 2010 available.

Comment: It is mapped from the following path: Connections > Get Filter Values From > InfoPath Form Web Part > [I now selected the two matching fields]. The issue with adding a lookup column is that I do not have anything to lookup. I want to have documents that are dropped into the item display be "tagged" with a field from the current item so that the attachments will still show after a refresh of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the Form web part, the list and the library in the same page?

How did you map the document according to the filtered list?

I suggest you could create a lookup column in the library to lookup the data from the list.

More reference:

[SharePoint 2013 - Simple Glossary using "HTML Form Web Part".](http://sharepointbitz.blogspot.com/2014/07/sharepoint-2013-simple-glossary-using.html)